# Android tablet with offline Web Application

Tags: android, html

We are planing to create an application for Android tablet using *HTML5* and local web storage for it.

Could we create site, which saved on cache, and create link on desktop or something like this. User should be able to open it without internet connection. If user click refresh site and no internet connection available, then no errors should appears. Site should reload from cache.

I knew that iPad allows to do it.

Does Android support this functionality?

Does Android support HTTPS AJAX queries?